# How to download multiple records from cloudkit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cloudkit, predicate

I am trying to download multiple items from cloud kit but I'm getting the error "cannot assign type value (CKQueryCursor!, NSError) -> () to type (CKQueryCursor?, NSError?) -> void"

```
let locationToLookFor = CLLocation() 
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "location = %@", locationToLookFor as CLLocation)
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Location", predicate: predicate)
let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
operation.recordFetchedBlock = self.recordFetchBlock
operation.queryCompletionBlock =
{
    [weak self]
    (cursor: CKQueryCursor!, error: NSError) in
    if(cursor != nil)
    {
        print("Fetching records")
        let newOperation = CKQueryOperation(cursor: cursor)
        operation.recordFetchedBlock = recordFetchBlock
        operation.queryCompletionBlock = operation.queryCompletionBlock
        self!.operationQueue.addOperation(newOperation)
    }
    else {
        print("We have fetched all data")
    }
}
operationQueue.addOperation(operation)
```

Comment: Your closure has an implicitly unwrapped `cursor` `CKQueryCursor!` but it should be optional `CKQueryCursor?`

Comment: I get the same error after the change @Paulw11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your closure signature doesn't match the required signature.  As shown in the error message, `cursor` should be optional as should `error`.  You will also get an error because you don't unwrap `cursor` when you supply it to the new operation.

Try:

```
operation.queryCompletionBlock =
{
    [weak self]
    (cursor: CKQueryCursor?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if let cursor = cursor
    {
        print("Fetching records")
        let newOperation = CKQueryOperation(cursor: cursor)
        operation.recordFetchedBlock = recordFetchBlock
        operation.queryCompletionBlock = operation.queryCompletionBlock
        self?.operationQueue.addOperation(newOperation)
    }
    else {
        print("We have fetched all data")
    }
}
```